# Letting air out of a balloon

Tags: thermodynamics

If air is let out of a balloon quickly, it can be idealized to be  an adiabatic process. We also know that when air goes out of a balloon, the air gets cooler. 
$$
ΔU= ΔQ- ΔW 
$$
As the the air gets cooler, $ΔU$ becomes negative. As the process is adiabatic $ΔQ=0$. Thus $ΔW$ must be positive, meaning the balloon must expand

But, we are literally letting air out of the balloon. It must deflate, should it not? How can it expand? This is not intuitive at all, to me. Can someone clear up this confusion?

Thanks for all help offered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very confusion lies in the fact that you are changing your system once the air rushes out. Initially the system was the air and balloon together. As the air rushes out, it is air which expands and thus work done is positive. So in a sense our system (air and the balloon) now occupies a larger volume and thus it is just a case of adiabatic expansion which causes cooling. You are thinking only of balloon and getting the false result.